# How to do integration using MCMC?

Tags: integration, markov-chains

I want to evaluate $I = \int_V f(\vec{x}) d\vec{x}$. The classical Monte Carlo method is to sample uniformly from within the integration volume $V$, and then compute $I \approx V \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f(\vec{x})$.

What if I sampled the $\vec{x}$'s using a MCMC approach (e.g. Metropolis-Hastings, slice sampling), how do I compute $I$? Specifically, if we use the above formular, what is $V$?

Comment: http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:fi4L0cVp5mAJ:www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/416/lect/l10-4.pdf+mcmc+integration&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgLCkoorGe89l2GN11NyK5sJmCdM8Ne6l1cQPR8G6q00htbKGVDuLQTXKKldKQNk9fCYkOu6Zzqw9V1BNKR85MArAEtmT_QdULqvcKb2UksgtNtrbt3Py0kM9nHiwLU2nx8EbHB&sig=AHIEtbSy6SMnv-eRW3DI4GmGNGBEWb6_IA

Comment: More generally, a search on mcmc + integration yields plenty of PDFs.

Comment: I've searched it before asking and I found the document you sent. According to that doc, I have to factorize $f(x)$ into $h(X)$ and $p(x)$ where $p$ a proper pdf. Am I right? What if I cannot do this factorization? Is the regular Monte Carlo only choice? 

Comment: I knew that sooner or later I'd see pdf used with two different meanings in close proximity. 

Comment: Am I missing a trivial point here? I still do not know the answer to my question :) The documents I found on the web --as I understand them-- does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

There are no significant changes when you switch from MC to MCMC.
The major concept remains the same. You draw your samples according to some probability distribution (which ideally has a form of your integrand, or as close as possible to it). Then instead of drawing i.i.d. samples, you just put a Metropolis move *on top* of your existing MC integration routine.

The only conceptual difference is that you have a Markov chain. That means that you have the current sample (state) and each time you generate a new sample from the current one. You should compute the acceptance probability carefully though.